# Generating numbers according to binomial and exponential distribution

Tags: python

I want to generate N(1000) numbers between [0,1] according to

1). Binomial Distribution: For binomial distributions if I use `s=np.random.binomial(10,0.5,1000)` then I get numbers between 1 to 10. Is there any way by which I may confine them to [0,1]

2). Exponential Distribution: For exponential if I use: `x=np.random.exponential(1,1000)` then too I am not able to obtain numbers between [0,1]

Is there some way by which I may generate floating point numbers between [0,1] in python according to binomial and exponential distribution.

Comment: Unclear why this has 2 downvotes, this is a legitimate question

Answer (score 1):

For Binomial Distribution:

```
vcnt = 10    
s=np.random.binomial(vcnt,0.5,1000)
s = [elem/float(vcnt) for elem in s]
```

Or you could do this with:

```
vcnt = 10    
s=np.random.binomial(vcnt,0.5,1000)/float(vcnt)
```

You could check the result with:

```
print(max(s))
print(min(s))
```

For Exponential Distribution this is more complex, because exponentially distributed random variables can take infinitely large (and small) values.

Comment: Ok thank you. If i want to generate "N" numbers (instead of 1000), then which values will "s" take. Also how did the magical (e-1)/9 come :) Also I am getting an array of all 0's?? which I am afraid should not be the case

Comment: If you generate "N" numbers code will be the same. In general form  
vcnt = 10  
s=np.random.binomial(vcnt,0.5,1000)  
s = [e/vcnt for e in s]

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to generate binomial distributed float numbers between 0 and 1. Why? Because in a binomial distribution the random variable N = number of successes and is therefor per definition an integer. What you can do is:

```
s = np.random.binomial(100, 0.5, size=1000)/100.
```

Edit: alternatively the equivalent form:

```
 s = np.random.binomial(100, 0.5, size=1000)/float(100)
```

To make sure you devide by a float and not an integer.

This will give you floats of form 0.xx according to a scaled binomial distribution with n (= number of trials) = 100, p = 0.5 . What do you get with this code? For every random variable drawn you flip a coin 100 times and add 1 to a counter every time it shows head (or tails, doesn't matter because you chose p to be 0.5). Due to the fact that any sequence of head and tails of length 100 has the same probability (namely p^100) you end up with a distribution according to all possible number of combinations:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

What you do by dividing by 100 is you define your random variable not to add 1 when head shows but 1/100. Attempt to increase n to 1000 or 10000 and you will come closer and closer to something that can be approximated by a normal distribution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html#numpy.random.normal

Note that p should not be to close to 0 or 1 for this approximation.

2) Here you probably want something like a Poisson distribution:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Poisson_approximation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2092/relationship-between-poisson-and-exponential-distribution

Comment: Ok...but I am getting an array of all 0's

Comment: Did you write the dot behind 100? The dot makes a float out of 100 (which would normally be an integer in python). If 100 stays an integer, your result will be an integer.